# Field doesn't have a default value with manyToMany Hibernate relationship

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

In manyToMany relationship, When I'm trying to add a new driver with selected vehicle from dropdown list, it's throwing an exception
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'vehicle_id' doesn't have a default value

However, if I set a default value in the DB, It works fine by inserting two different rows to the (driver_series_stats_xref) table, one for what I’m trying to add and other row for the default value that I set in the db.

Entity.java

```
@Column(name="driver_id", unique = true,  nullable=false)
private Long driverId;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

 @ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "driver_series_stats_xref",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id", referencedColumnName ="vehicle_id"))
private List<Vehicle> listOfVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
//getter and setter
```

the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `driver_vehicle_xref` (
`driver_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`vehicle_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`starts_num` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`driver_id`, `vehicle_id`),
INDEX `fk_driver_vehicle_xref_2` (`vehicle_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_driver_vehicle_xref_1` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id`) REFERENCES `driver` (`driver_id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_driver_vehicle_xref_2` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`vehicle_id`)
```

)

driverDao.java

```
   public Long addorUpdateDriver(final Driver driver) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(driver);
    return driver.getDriverId();
}
```

driverService.java

```
 @Transactional
public Long addToDriver(Driver driver, Vehicle vehicle) {
    vehicle = vehicleDao.getVehicleById(vehicle.getVehicleId());
    driver.getListOfVehicles().add(vehicle);
    Long driverId = driverDao.addorUpdateDriver(driver);
    driver.setDriverId(driverId);
    return driverId;
}
```

controller.java(post method)

```
public String addDriverSubmit(@ModelAttribute Driver driver, Vehicle vehicle, BindingResult result, @RequestParam (value="mode") String mode,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
String vehicleId = request.getParameter("vehicleId");
    request.getAttribute("driverId");
    if("Save".equalsIgnoreCase(mode)) {
        driverService.addToDriver(driver, vehicle);
    }
```

error meesage
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1364]; could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

and
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'vehicle_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Without your code we can't find the bug. Show a minimal test case reproducing the problem.